# Do POTS ports still function on ONTs in bridge mode

Tags: fiber

I have a FTTH service where the ISP has provided me with internet + voice, a ONT is connected in router mode.

I want to use my own router and set the ONT in bridge mode connected to my router, will the POTS/Tel ports on the ONT still function in bridge mode?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. If your provider is using VoIP, where ONT unit is acting as SIP client, then it wont be functional. In this VoIP setup, IP address of ONT is needed - ONT needs to be in router mode.

Your provider can use other Voice solution based on PON technology (optical technology for your FTTH solution), but I dont think this is a common approach.